# Find the value of the contour integral $ \oint \frac {3z^3 + 2}{(z-1)(z^2+9)} dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

$ \oint \frac {3z^3 + 2}{(z-1)(z^2+9)} dz$  taken counterclockwise around circles:
(a) |z-2| = 2; (b) |z| = 4

My Attempt:

The circle of radius 2 centered at z = 2 only encloses the singularity z = 1 but I'm not sure whether I can use the Cauchy integral formula with it.

The circle of radius 4 centered at the origin encloses all the singular points, namely:
z = 1, +3i, -3i (from $(z^2 +9) -> (z-3i)(z+3i) $)
So can I just do
$ \oint \frac {3z^3 + 2}{(z-1)(z^2+9)} dz = 2\pi i (\sum residues) ?$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, think about the contours and what singularities they enclose. You should know that by Cauchy's Theorem a closed integral around a function that is analytic on an in the contour is zero. However, we are going to have some singularities here because of the denominator.

1. z = 1
2. $z^2+9=0 \Rightarrow z = 3i, -3i$

You did this. Nice!

**Use Cauchy's Integral Formula.**

Part (a) is a circle of radius two centered at 2. It will enclose z = 1.

$\oint \frac{3z^3+2}{(z-1)(z+3i)(z-3i)}dz = 2\pi i \left[\left.\left(\frac{3z^3+2}{z^2+9}\right)\right|_{z=1}\right]$

Part (b) will enclose everything.

$\oint \frac{3z^3+2}{(z-1)(z+3i)(z-3i)}dz = 2\pi i \left[\left.\left(\frac{3z^3+2}{z^2+9}\right)\right|_{z=1}+\left.\left(\frac{3z^3+2}{(z-1)(z+3i)}\right)\right|_{z=3i}+\left.\left(\frac{3z^3+2}{(z-1)(z-3i)}\right)\right|_{z=-3i}\right]$

Comment: Wouldn't the circle of radius 2 centered at z = 2 only enclose the singularity z = 1?